# Scan multiple pages with ADF scanner using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, wia, scanning

I am writing a Microsoft Access application and I want to enable the user to scan multiple pages to a single PDF format. The conversion to PDF works fine once I have all the pages scanned. Here's my code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const WIA_FORMAT_JPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

Public Function MyScan()
  Dim ComDialog As WIA.CommonDialog
  Dim DevMgr As WIA.DeviceManager
  Dim DevInfo As WIA.DeviceInfo
  Dim dev As WIA.Device
  Dim img As WIA.ImageFile
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim wiaScanner As WIA.Device

  Set ComDialog = New WIA.CommonDialog
  Set wiaScanner = ComDialog.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, False, True)

  Set DevMgr = New WIA.DeviceManager

  For i = 1 To DevMgr.DeviceInfos().Count
    If DevMgr.DeviceInfos(i).DeviceID = wiaScanner.DeviceID Then
      Set DevInfo = DevMgr.DeviceInfos(i)
    End If
  Next i

  Set dev = DevInfo.Connect

  Set img = dev.Items(1).Transfer(WIA_FORMAT_JPEG)

  img.SaveFile "C:\img.jpg"

  Set img = Nothing
  Set dev = Nothing
  Set DevInfo = Nothing
  Set DevMgr = Nothing
  Set ComDialog = Nothing


End Function
```

Of course it is important to say that my scanner is [Avision AV121](http://avision.com/usa/products/av121.html) with an automatic document feeder.

My problem is that `Set img = dev.Items(1).Transfer(WIA_FORMAT_JPEG)` scans ALL the pages at once (and not just a single page) but I only see the first one in the image file. Because all the pages are scanned at once, I can't do it in a loop - an error will be raised in the second iteration (saying that the feeder is empty as it really is) and I still only have the first page scanned.

I would like to state that this seems to be a common problem. I've read a lot of threads regarding this problem, but didn't find anything that answered my question.

I hope to find help here, I am really frustrated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem myself.

I cannot remember where I found that this is probably a limitation of WIA, a bug I think. Maybe only in some circumstances.

My solution was to use a 3rd party scanning control.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still working on the problem, I modified this code from JIM's code  to work with a scanner with a ADF. It scans the documents continuously unlimit pages and stores them as a jpeg file temporarily. It then outputs a report to a pdf. This is the only way I can figure out scanning multiple documents using an ADF scanner.

---

```
'Requirements:
'Must include reference to Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition 2.0 dll
'Create a table named scantemp. Create ID column as Autonumber. Create 2nd column named Picture with Text as datatype.
'Create a continuous report named rptscan. Set scantemp table as recordsource. Add image control to report and set Picture
'as the control source. Make the image control the size of an 8.5 x 11 sheet so that the whole document appears normally when the
'create textbox set name txt_id for enter PDF files name
'report is exported to pdf.
'For use with a scanner that continually scans documents until the ADF tray is empty unlimit pages.

option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Const WIA_FORMAT_JPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

Public Sub ScanDocs()

    Dim intPages As Integer 'number of pages
    Dim img As WIA.ImageFile 
    Dim strPath As String 
    Dim strFileJPG As String

    strPath = CurrentProject.Path 'set path to save files
    intPages = 1


On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

 'scan
ScanStrat:

    Dim DialogScan As New WIA.CommonDialog, dpi As Integer, pp As Integer, l    As Integer
    dpi = 250
    Dim Scanner As WIA.Device
    Set Scanner = DialogScan.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, False, False)

    'set properties device
        Scanner.Properties("3088").Value = 1 'Automatic Document Feeder
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6146").Value = 4 'Colour intent
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6147").Value = dpi 'DPI horizontal
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6148").Value = dpi 'DPI vertical
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6149").Value = 0 'x point to start scan
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6150").Value = 0 'y point to start scan
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6151").Value = 8.27 * dpi  'Horizontal extent
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6152").Value = 11.7 * dpi    'Vertical extent for A4
        Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6154").Value = 80 'brightness
      '  Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6155").Value = 30 'contrast

 'Start Scan if err number -2145320957 Scan document finish 

    Do While Err.Number <> -2145320957 'error number is ADF status don't feed document

        Set img = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer(WIA_FORMAT_JPEG) 
        strFileJPG = strPath & "\FileScan\temp\" & CStr(intPages) & ".jpg"
        img.SaveFile (strFileJPG) 'save files .jpg in temp folder
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False 
       DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG & "')" 'insert picture temp to table scan temp

        intPages = intPages + 1 'add number pages
   Loop

'after finish scan start convert to pdf
StartPDFConversion: 

    Dim strFilePDF As String '
    Dim RptName As String
    strFilePDF = CurrentProject.Path & "\FileScan\" & txt_id.Value & ".pdf" 'pdf file name by textbox
    RptName = "rptScan" 'report picture file for export to PDF 
    DoCmd.OpenReport RptName, acViewDesign, , , acHidden
    DoCmd.Close acReport, RptName, acSaveYes
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, RptName, acFormatPDF, strFilePDF
    DoCmd.RunSQL "delete from scantemp" 'delete all data from table scantemp



DeleteTemp:
'delete files temp (JPG)
Dim i As Integer
Dim filesname As String
i = 1

'loop pages number (intpages)
Do While i < intPages
    filesname = CurrentProject.Path & "\FileScan\temp\" & i & ".jpg"

    If Dir(filesname) <> "" Then
        'SetAttr filesname, vbNormal
        Kill filesname
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop


MsgBox ("done")
    Exit Sub


ErrorHandler:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case -2145320957
    If intPages = 1 Then
        MsgBox ("not found document to scan")
        Exit Sub
    Else
      GoTo StartPDFConversion
      End If
    End Select


 MsgBox "Error" & ":  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " _
    & Err.Description, vbExclamation, Me.Name & ".ScanDocs"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified this code to work with a scanner with a ADF. It scans the documents continuously up to 10 pages and stores them as a jpeg file temporarily. It then outputs a report to a pdf. This is the only way I can figure out scanning multiple documents using an ADF scanner using WIA without using a 3rd party app.

```
'This code was originally designed by http://kbase.icbconsulting.com/vba/scan-documents-into-an-access-database
    'Details: This code will continually scan up to 10 documents using a scanner with an Automatic Document Feeder(ADF) and then export the jpeg
    'images to (1) pdf file.
    'Code tested using an HP OfficeJet 6600 Wireless All-in-one Printer.

'Requirements:
'Must include reference to Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition 2.0 dll
'Create a table named scantemp. Create ID column as Autonumber. Create 2nd column named Picture with Text as datatype.
'Create a continuous report named rptscan. Set scantemp table as recordsource. Add image control to report and set Picture
'as the control source. Make the image control the size of an 8.5 x 11 sheet so that the whole document appears normally when the
'report is exported to pdf.
'For use with a scanner that continually scans documents until the ADF tray is empty.

'NOTE: I previosuly coded this to scan up to 20 documents at once. It would always get to the 11th or 12th page and then Access 2010
'would crash (Not Responding). It would be interesting to see if someone can come up with a way to scan more that 10 documents
'with this code.

Public Sub ScanDocs()
'ErrorHandler traps feeder empty error after all documents are scanned, then begins jpeg-to-pdf file conversion
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Initial Document Load into scanner
If MsgBox("Set documents (Max. 10) in the Automatic Document Feeder and then click OK.", vbOKCancel, "Scan Start") = vbCancel Then
MsgBox ("Scan Canceled")
GoTo ProcedureExit
Else
GoTo ScanStart
End If

ScanStart:
'Setup WIA imaging device for scanning
Dim Dialog1 As New WIA.CommonDialog, dpi As Integer, PP As Integer, l As Integer
dpi = 300
Dim Scanner As WIA.Device
Set Scanner = Dialog1.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, False, False)

'Set Document Properties and Feeder Setup
Scanner.Properties("3088").Value = 1 'Automatic Document Feeder
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6146").Value = 4 'Colour intent
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6147").Value = dpi 'DPI horizontal
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6148").Value = dpi 'DPI vertical
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6149").Value = 0 'x point to start scan
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6150").Value = 0 'y point to start scan
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6151").Value = 8.5 * dpi  'Horizontal extent
Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6152").Value = 11# * dpi   'Vertical extent for letter
'Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6154").Value = -30 'brightness
'Scanner.Items(1).Properties("6155").Value = 30 'contrast

'Start first page scan
    Dim intPages As Integer
    Dim img As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG As String
    strFileJPG = "c:\1.jpg"
    img.SaveFile (strFileJPG)
    intPages = 1
'Then every subsequent scan thereafter
    Dim img2 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img2 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG2 As String
    strFileJPG2 = "c:\2.jpg"
    img2.SaveFile (strFileJPG2)
    intPages = intPages + 1


    Dim img3 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img3 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG3 As String
    strFileJPG3 = "c:\3.jpg"
    img3.SaveFile (strFileJPG3)
    intPages = intPages + 1


    Dim img4 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img4 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG4 As String
    strFileJPG4 = "c:\4.jpg"
    img4.SaveFile (strFileJPG4)
    intPages = intPages + 1

    Dim img5 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img5 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG5 As String
    strFileJPG5 = "c:\5.jpg"
    img5.SaveFile (strFileJPG5)
    intPages = intPages + 1

    Dim img6 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img6 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG6 As String
    strFileJPG6 = "c:\6.jpg"
    img6.SaveFile (strFileJPG6)
    intPages = intPages + 1

    Dim img7 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img7 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG7 As String
    strFileJPG7 = "c:\7.jpg"
    img7.SaveFile (strFileJPG7)
    intPages = intPages + 1

    Dim img8 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img8 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG8 As String
    strFileJPG8 = "c:\8.jpg"
    img8.SaveFile (strFileJPG8)
    intPages = intPages + 1

    Dim img9 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img9 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG9 As String
    strFileJPG9 = "c:\9.jpg"
    img9.SaveFile (strFileJPG9)
    intPages = intPages + 1

    Dim img10 As WIA.ImageFile
    Set img10 = Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}")
    Dim strFileJPG10 As String
    strFileJPG10 = "c:\10.jpg"
    img10.SaveFile (strFileJPG10)
    intPages = intPages + 1

'Starts the jpeg-to-pdf conversion
StartPDFConversion:
Dim strFilePDF As String

'set pdf output path
strFilePDF = "c:\pdf.pdf"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'delete previously processed images from scantemp table
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete from scantemp"

'insert all newly scanned images into scantemp table
DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG & "')"
If intPages >= 2 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG2 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 3 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG3 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 4 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG4 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 5 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG5 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 6 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG6 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 7 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG7 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 8 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG8 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 9 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG9 & "')"
End If
If intPages >= 10 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into scantemp (picture) values ('" & strFileJPG10 & "')"
End If

'output rptscan to predefined file path
Dim RptName As String
RptName = "rptScan"
DoCmd.OpenReport RptName, acViewDesign, , , acHidden
DoCmd.Close acReport, RptName, acSaveYes
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, RptName, acFormatPDF, strFilePDF

'delete all jpeg files after report output
Dim fso46 As New FileSystemObject
fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG
If intPages = 2 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
ElseIf intPages = 3 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
ElseIf intPages = 4 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG4
ElseIf intPages = 5 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG4
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG5
ElseIf intPages = 6 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG4
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG5
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG6
ElseIf intPages = 7 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG4
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG5
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG6
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG7
ElseIf intPages = 8 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG4
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG5
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG6
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG7
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG8
ElseIf intPages = 9 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG4
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG5
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG6
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG7
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG8
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG9
ElseIf intPages = 10 Then
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG2
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG3
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG4
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG5
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG6
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG7
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG8
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG9
        fso46.DeleteFile strFileJPG10
End If
Set fso46 = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox ("Done!")

ProcedureExit:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
'Traps 'out of paper error.' Asks user if all documents were scanned properly, if yes is chosen, start PDF conversion, if no, restarts
'scan subroutine.
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2145320957
            If MsgBox("Were all documents successfully scanned?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Scan") = vbYes Then
                GoTo StartPDFConversion
            Else
                Call scan
            End If
    End Select

'Handles any other errors in subroutine
    MsgBox "Error" & ":  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " _
        & Err.Description, vbExclamation, Me.Name & ".ScanDocs"
    Resume ProcedureExit

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you read the OP's question. When he calls `Items(1).Transfer` the first time, all the pages are scanned through the feeder. The next time the `Transfer` method is called, it looks for pages in the feeder and doesn't find any, at which point it throws an error. (There is also no way to access the other images through the `Scanner` object.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Writing in MS Access. To scan from the scanner Broter 7065, with ADF, in a single PDF file. And no time to write your own code. A lot searched, but found not what I needed.
The problem was solved with the help of the program "quick scan Command line TWAIN scanning"http://www.burrotech.com/quickscan/

```
Private Sub Button27_Click()
Dim Nomer As Integer
Nomer = Forms!Nakladnaya!NomerLink ' invoice number from form
Shell CurrentProject.Path & "\quickscan.exe resolution 100 pdf showprogress filename " & CurrentProject.Path & "\scan\ScanN¹" & Nomer & "23.pdf " 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still working on the problem, I found the following solutions:

Depending on which formatID one uses for the Scanner.Items(1).Transfer("formatID"), my scanner either stopped after scanning 1 paper or continued scanning (it only worked with BMP for me, and I am using an HP Officejet J4680).

I then used as variable say ADFstatus that reads whether there is still a paper in the feeder and used this to create a while loop.(wiaScanner.Properties.Item("3087")). I then saved each scanned image separately, and it causes the ADF scanner to stop after each scan instead of scanning all papers at once.

for example:

```
Dim wiaImg As WIA.ImageFile
ADFStatus = wiaScanner.Properties.Item("3087").Value
counter = 0

While ADFStatus
    counter = counter + 1
    Set wiaImg = wiaScanner.Items(1).Transfer(WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatBMP)
    wiaImg.SaveFile ("C:\Test\" & counter & ".bmp")
    Set wiaImg = Nothing
    ADFStatus = wiaScanner.Properties.Item("3087").Value
Wend
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to acquire the images as wiaFormatTIFF which will result in a multi-page tiff. You can then loop through each page in the tiff and save each if you require separate images.

Answer (score 0):

It's a not supported drive.
I solve this installing original Twain Drive for Brother DCP-8157