How do I set the default scan method for a printer when doing pull scanning from a Microsoft Access database?
I have a setup where a MS Access database can do pull scanning with a Canon printer by using the Microsoft WIA library and Color Network ScanGear 2. The printer has both a top tray feeder and a glass pane to scan from. By default, my setup is scanning from the glass pane. Does anyone know how to set it so that scan happens from the top tray feeder? Below are my current default settings for scanning.
Edit: I updated my code below. I added the 3088 property and removed the other properties, but now there is an error one the Transfer line:

-2147024809 - The parameter is incorrect.

Function ScanJpeg(strFile As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrLabel
 
   Dim wiaDialog As New WIA.CommonDialog
   Dim wiaScanner As WIA.device
   Dim wiaImg As New WIA.ImageFile

   ScanJpeg = False
   
   Set wiaScanner = wiaDialog.ShowSelectDevice
   wiaScanner.Properties("3088").Value = 1

   Set wiaImg = wiaScanner.Items(1).Transfer(wiaFormatJPEG) 'ERROR POINTS HERE
   
   wiaImg.SaveFile strFile

   ScanJpeg = True
   
ExitLabel:
On Error Resume Next

   Set wiaImg = Nothing
   Set wiaScanner = Nothing
   Set wiaDialog = Nothing
   Exit Function
   
ErrLabel:

   ErrHandler Err.Number, Err.Description
   Resume ExitLabel

End Function

Is there any other info I can provide? I still really need help here.

Any help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008480/scan-multiple-pages-with-adf-scanner-using-vba

@June7 no, that question is about handling a printer that scans all documents at once. I need a way to tell my device to scan from the feeder instead of from the glass pane.

Another discussion which leads back to the first link referenced https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/adf-scanner-in-access.312707/

@June7 I modified the code from what I saw in those others answers, but now I'm getting a different error. I've updated my question to show what I did. Do you know why this error might be showing up?

Sorry, I got nothing else.
